# Clients do not register with Eureka server

Tags: java, spring, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix, service-discovery

I have my Eureka server (registry) upend running. However, it shows that it is registered, but not available.

I'm going off of the tutorial found [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/service-registration-and-discovery/) which says to turn off logging and prevent the server from registering itself.

Edit: have confirmed the problem is not with the server. it can now register itself. additionally, I used the client from this demo (in a wholly separate project) which registers itself with my server.

My client now does not run. Here are the dependencies from the pom file:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.nt.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>nt-spring-data-marklogic</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-commons</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.RC3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>1.11</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.11</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is the client main file:

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.marklogic.repository.config.EnableMarkLogicRepositories;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.EnableDiscoveryClient;


@EnableDiscoveryClient
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableMarkLogicRepositories("com.example.repository")
@ComponentScan({"com.id.example"})
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class ClientApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Starting app...");
        SpringApplication.run(ClientApp.class, args);    

    }
}
```

Here is the error:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::       (v1.5.10.RELEASE)

[2018-04-23 16:27:44.811] - 91242 INFO [main] --- org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService: Starting service [Tomcat]
[2018-04-23 16:27:44.816] - 91242 INFO [main] --- org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.27
[2018-04-23 16:27:45.163] - 91242 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] --- org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]: Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
[2018-04-23 16:28:04.271] - 91242 INFO [main] --- org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService: Stopping service [Tomcat]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'eurekaAutoServiceRegistration'; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:348)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:151)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:114)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:880)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:144)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
    at com.ibm.tsd.TradeServiceDemoApplication.main(TradeServiceDemoApplication.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaServiceRegistry.maybeInitializeClient(EurekaServiceRegistry.java:56)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaServiceRegistry.register(EurekaServiceRegistry.java:37)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.start(EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.java:80)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:175)
    ... 14 more
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Maybe you should start investigation with removing the **spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server** dependency from the client side. Next, you restart Eureka Server then the Client Server and check __http(s)://eurekaserverurl/eureka/apps__

Comment: I think I've done that before to no avail. But wouldn't that only affect the tests, not the main application itself given the scope?

Comment: Try changing `@EnableDiscoveryClient` by `@EnableEurekaClient`

Comment: Can you share your application.properties (or .yml) with your configuration ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to separate your "Server-application" (let's call it `EurekaServerApplication`) from your "Client-application" (let's call it EurekaClientApplication):

In your Server-application add the `eureka-server` dependency:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

Your Server-application must be decorated with the `@EnableEurekaServer` annotation

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class EurekaServerApplication {..}
```

Add the 'eureka-client' dependency to the `pom.xml` of your Client-application :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>           
</dependency>
```

In your client `application.properties` or `application.yml` you must have:

```
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
```

The port value 8761 must be of course the same as the one in your Server-application:

```
server:
  port: ${PORT:8761}
```

Note: You don't need to decorate the ClientEurekaApplication with the `@EnableEurekaClient` or `@EnableDiscoveryClient` annotation to let your client be discovered from/by the ServerEurekaApplication.

Answer (score 0):

I am using configurations for clients like this (`yml`):

```
server:
  port: 8080
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
spring:
  application:
    name: clientname
```

You can keep using your `application.properties` instead of `yml`. Simply add `spring.application.name=applicationname`

Please check if you forgot to set an `applicationname`.
Also make sure your `discovery-service` is up before you start your `client`.

To see your `eureka-service` you would need to go to `http://localhost:8761`.
To access your `client` use `http://localhost:8761/clientname`

Comment: It looks like I had to use `application.yml` instead of `application.properties` for the eureka-service -- so now it does actually go to port 8761. I even enabled the server to register itself and it does. However, I still can't get my client to register. I have set the name as well.

Comment: Can you please share the code of your client `main`-class?

Comment: Hi @elp -- I believe the problem is with the client. I've added the client main class, its dependencies, and the (new) error message. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have this error in one project I have to upgrade and I fix it eliminating or deleting some library dependency in maven. It caused problems when picking the right library for something related to Jackson 5 or Jersey.

See your dependency hierarchy and start playing or ordering things.

Comment: This doesn't seem to provide a solution.

Comment: You have to see the dependecy hierarchy to know where is the fault. i can't do that for you.